# Renaming multiple files which match UNIX find keyword

Tags: shell-script, find, rename

I have the following output from find command for finding files containing `yyy` in name:

```
./plonetheme/xxx/yyy-logo.png
./plonetheme/xxx/profiles/default/plonetheme.yyy_various.txt
./plonetheme/xxx/skins/plonetheme_yyy_custom_images
./plonetheme/xxx/skins/plonetheme_yyy_custom_images/CONTENT.txt
./plonetheme/xxx/skins/plonetheme_yyy_custom_templates
./plonetheme/xxx/skins/plonetheme_yyy_custom_templates/CONTENT.txt
./plonetheme/xxx/skins/plonetheme_yyy_custom_templates/main_template.pt
./plonetheme/xxx/skins/plonetheme_yyy_styles
./plonetheme/xxx/skins/plonetheme_yyy_styles/base_properties.props
./plonetheme/xxx/skins/plonetheme_yyy_styles/CONTENT.txt
```

How I would rename all file so that string `yyy` is replaced with `zzz`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [bash string manipulation](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/string-manipulation.html) to achieve what you want:

```
find PATH/PATTERN -exec bash -c 'mv "$0" "${0/yyy/zzz}"' {} \;
```

The `-exec` switch executes the command up to the escaped `;`, where `{}` is the path of ther file that's currently handled.

`bash -c 'mv "$0" "${0/cix/stix}"' {}` passes that path as an argument to bash, which moves `$0` (the first argument, e.g., `./plonetheme/xxx/yyy-logo.png`) to `${0/yyy/zzz}` (the first manipulated argument, e.g., `./plonetheme/xxx/zzz-logo.png`).

Answer (score 2):

As described [here](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001), you can use `-print0` and `read -r -d''`:

```
find /path/to/files -type f -print0 | while IFS= read -r -d '' file; do
    mv "$file" "${file/yyy/zzz}"
done
```